# Is it possible to set up Google Analytics for an Ionic 2 web app?

Tags: google-analytics, ionic2

We have an Ionic 2 app that will be deployed on iOS, Android and web.  We have Google Analytics set up for the mobile versions.

Is it possible to set this up for the web version as well?  If so, are there any references for how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase to link all your apps to your google analytics account.